# Grid system to align form element using bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<?php echo form_open('secure/register', 'class="form"', 'role="form"'); ?>
<div class="page-header">
    <h2><?php echo lang('reg_title'); ?></h2>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="text-center">
        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><?php echo lang('register_btn'); ?></button>
    </div>
</div>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

This is the form I created for registration.

It layout like that now:

```
Email
_________________________
Password
_________________________
          [Reg]
```

it takes 100% of the width inside container.

So the problem is

1) How can I make the form smaller and align to center, say, takes only 60% width of the container? Then the left has 20% empty space and right at 20% empty space

2) Also, how can I create form in this layout?

```
Email
_________________________
Password
_________________________
Contact
FirstName___ LastName____
          [Reg]
```

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap your div into a div like

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="text-center">
        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><?php echo lang('register_btn'); ?></button>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

this make your form align at center with width of 66.6% and 16.7% margin on every side. if you want this in small size farm also than add class `col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2` .

For your second question you can use inline form or horizontal form. Mare info [Read here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms)
you can use form and form horizontal class together as from bootstrap docs

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: but can I use class="form-horizontal" and class="form" at the same form?

Comment: Thanks for the detail but how about the two form group at one line? e.g. for your second example add the password form at the same line: email _____ password_____ like this. Thanks

Comment: you can use `form-inline` class in form instead of form-horizontal or wrap your both form-group in two div with class `col-md-6`

Answer (score 1):

The user @VikasRana has covered the most of what had to be done, however I'll elaborate a bit.

If you aren't aware, Bootstrap consists of grid system to position your elements systematic manner. Each row is divided into 12 columns. You can view the grid layout [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic).

For your problem:

1) Like the answer above says, wrap it in class `<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2"></div>` and wrap that too inside `<div class="container"></div>`. `container` has prefixed width for each view-port so this should make your form look more short and in center. You can see the **[demo here](http://www.bootply.com/9HOnvGlYlZ)**. On mobile device, it's best to have your form width 100% so you could leave out the `col-sm-*` classes which are used to design for smaller-viewports.

2) For the second one, you could use the `form-inline` class to display both the `<label>` and `<input>` on the same line. To make their widths equal and leave spacing between, you could wrap each in `col-md-6` class. **[Demo here.](http://www.bootply.com/ZrtlzeyJrQ#)**

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 placeholders for the blank spaces and assign Bootstrap's weighting to all the containers in a row. The total weighting value must sum up to 12, so use something like 2-8-2.

http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/